# How do I use a Spring Service method in a Spring Security expression?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a spring Service and want to use a method in the service combined with the current user in a spring security expression. I saw [another question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743565/spring-expression-language-and-spring-security-3-accessing-bean-reference-in-p) that led me to believe something like this was possible. I'm using spring 3.1.2.

```
@Service("orgService")
public class DefaultOrganizationService implements OrganizationService {
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean isOrgAdmin(String username) 
    {   
       return true;
    }
}
```

Then in a jsp, I have something like this:

```
<sec:authorize access="orgService.isOrgAdmin(principal.name)">
    USER IS ORG ADMIN
</sec:authorize>
```

However, when I run my web app with this setup, I get

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'orgService' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot'
```

I've tried expressions with both "@orgService..." and "orgService..."

Is what I'm trying to do possible, or do I need to implement a [PermissionEvaluator](http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/03/spring-security-by-example-securing.html)?

Comment: Do you get the same error with and without `@`? Please, post both. The error you posted looks good for case without `@`. I'm curious about the error message for `@orgService..`

Comment: It turns out I had a different error with the "@" (related to the principal). Using the "@" does in fact let spring security recognize the bean name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@orgService` should work, for Spring Security starting from [Version 3.1.0.RC2](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/changelog.html)

`[SEC-1723] - Support use of bean names in expressions via @beanName notation`

---

`I'm using spring 3.1.2.`

I think that you are using an old version of Spring Security, not Spring.