# @PreAuthorize with Bean in expression (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spelevaluationexception

Simple question, I got a @Service class `@Autowired` up in my controller.

Trying to put a little security on one of the methods in my controller. So for simplicity I did this to test

```
@PreAuthorize("@myService.helloThere()")
public void someControllerMethod() {
    ...
}
```

But no success really. Getting an exception during method call.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression
>   '@myService.helloThere()'

Am I missing something with EL here?

#### Update

Just adding the last Caused by exception

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
>   EL1057E:(pos 1): No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve
>   access to bean 'dummyServiceImpl'

Now I don't understand why it wouldn't be accesible in the StandardEvaluationContext if I'm using @Autowired ?

#### Update 2

Since I had my own Role Hierarchy hooked up in a custom `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` extended class, the `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` did not have the `applicationContext` set by default. I'm not sure why this is by design or I was missing something obvious. I searched the reference pages and found another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328124/no-bean-resolver-registered-in-the-context-to-resolve-access-to-bean) that helped me solve the problem. I'm posting the updated security configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class GlobalMethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext; //added this

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {           
        final DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();

        handler.setApplicationContext(applicationContext); //added this
        RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();

        roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER_MANAGER > ROLE_USER");
        handler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
        return handler;
    }
}
```

Comment: What logic are you going to write in `@myService.helloThere()`? Why don't you expect the user to just have some specific role?

Comment: You are missing a bean.

Comment: @XtremeBiker eg ensuring authenticated user cannot add a user of higher authority. Has role solves one half of the equation but there are corner cases I guess that I like to extract.

Comment: @RomanC what do you mean? My class is auto wired?

Comment: @HajderRabiee If it's autowired then you ok.

Comment: It's because Configuration class sets it during it's postProcessing. Client code is only called later and never gets this. Whole GlobalMethodSecurity class approach is... opinionated to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

> @PreAuthorize("myService.helloThere()")

Comment: Nope, the syntax is @beanName. However I updated the question, I don't understand why the service is not available in the evaluation context.